# Android photo editor, opengl es 2.0 or canvas

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm new to Android and OpenGL (ES 2.0) and my project is related to work with photos, something like photoeditor.

Could you please clarify - will it be useful to use OpenGL in such only-2d project?

My concern is that work with OpenGL ES is much harder(since I've just started to learn it) than work with canvas. But if I know that OpenGL will benefit in this task - I will try to apply it.

Thanks!

Comment: depends on what functions you want to implement in your photo editor, for a simple one, canvas should be good enough.

Comment: @Mindsonic Some basic functions related to rotations, drawing lines and points, determining coordinates in pixels.. Maybe some basic operations with contrast/brightness

Comment: then Canvas should be enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going for some animation related stuffs with your photos then you should definitely go for OpenGL/OpenGLES, you can learn OpenGLES from this [Nehe link](http://nehe.gamedev.net/),

but if you are not opting for animation kind of stuffs, just plain and simple photo editing, and if you think animation won't be required for you in near future,

then you should just use Canvas,

you can try to check out OpenCV too, if that helps

OpenGL takes a huge lot time to understand properly, and then integrate it as you wish, so if not necessary then it is time waste if you don't need it, but knowledge is always useful.

Comment: I just want to add a comment after half a year of development of my android app: I decided to use canvas and it was great and applicable to the present moment. But now, when I added a lot of features and I need to continue adding new features related to work with graphics - I got bad performance, so now I'm going to rewrite all graphics-related code with OpenGL. Just a minor comment for those people who will read this answer with the same situation... =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do 2D operations,I think you can use `Canvas`,with `android.graphics.Camera` and `android.graphics.Matrix`.They are complete.But they are not well documented.

Answer (score 0):

I'll always go for the more complete solution. In this case OpenGL ES, because even if you might only need to do some simple editing nowadays, it's almost sure that you expand your project and, at some point in the future then you'll need some more complex functions and then, you'll need OpenGL.
It's not reinventing the wheel, but being able to control in deep every functionality of your app.
Regards.

Comment: Can you expand on what operations "you'll need OpenGL" for? Most image-editing processes work with pixel coordinates, and Matrices are very flexible for doing transformations. I think if you gave a few examples, it will be a better-all-around answer.

Comment: Everything that is displayed on the screen is processed in a pixel basis, that's for sure, 'cause that is the physical unit in the screen of the device. There are several buffers involved in the process of getting an image displayed in a handset's screen. A simple example is the use of the filter perspective correction, or to add perspective to an image. Another example of why I would use OpenGL over canvas in this case, is the possibility to add animated preview to build an animated GIF, or to render several keyframes into a .AVI output file. Regards.

Comment: I should also add that EVERY operation is governed (of course) by matrix algebra.

Comment: I wasn't saying you were wrong, just that you might want to incorporate that into the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would really avoid opengl es that should really be left to gaming only.
Go with standard 2d canvas and to implement effects and similar stuff go with Renderscript that has many features as built in

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html

Comment: Could you please provide additional details, can OpenGL bring here some benefits? As I understand, canvas is based on OpenGL, so it should be slower(though perhaps marginally)?